# Can we auto submit wufoo form

Tags: wufoo

I have posting values from my site to wufoo, I am sending all values using url, getting all values in wufoo form also but i want to submit that form directly.
see following url

```
   window.location = "https://ravimule.wufoo.com/forms/r1rb2r1d0z1yzlh/def/Field1=test@gmail.com&Field2=test&Field3=test&Field4=abc";
```

Comment: Did you get an answer yet?